# После переноса сайта на другой сервер перестала работать почта

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

В коде используется PHPMailer для заявок с сайта, там есть 2 адреса no-reply@mydomain.ru который отправляет заявки на sales@mydomain.ru почтовые ящики, как я понимаю, находятся на mail.ru

Почему перестали работать обе почты? Значит ли это что старый сервер использовал свой SMTP server? Как починить почту sales@mydomain.ru? 
P.S.  не хотелось бы поднимать на новом сервере SMTP, всегда использую gmail для отправки заявок с сайта.

Comment: Попробуйте отправить письмо средствами php функции:
 
mail("email@example.com", "Тема", "Сообщение"); Вероятнее всего у вас на самом сервере не настроена почта

Comment: Ну, надо было читать настройки почты на старом сервере)

Comment: @andreymal не было возможности

Comment: попробовала отправить письмо на этот адрес sales@mydomain.ru пришел ответ 550 relay not permitted. Поменяла  MX записи, жду когда обновятся, надеюсь это решит мою проблему

Comment: Проверьте спам в ящике

Comment: `всегда использую gmail для отправки заявок с сайта` для отправки используется SMTP?

Answer (score 0):

Смена MX-записи в соответсвии с mail.ru "оживила" почту sales@mydomain.ru. Но Phpmailer все равно не срабатывал, видимо действительно нужно настраивать почту на новом сервере. 
Но я считаю, что моя проблема решена. Главное что на sales@mydomain.ru стали приходить заявки, а для их отправки переписала запрос через SMTP сервер gmail.